# How to get the posts of a user (who is currently logged in) in django?

Tags: python, django

When a user logged in and went to his/her account they must see there old posts, what they have uploaded in past. If tried if statement in template by comparing current logged in user (request.user) and the users available in database. If, if condition is true than all the posts which are related to that user must be visible in my account page. But this if condition is not working. When i remove this condition it shows all of the posts whether these posts are related or uploaded by the user or not. And when i apply this condition it shows nothing, no error, it shows my navbar only which means rest of the code is fine the problem is with if statement.

Template :

```
{% for i in userstweet %}
    {% if request.user==i.user  %}
        Username : {{i.user}}
        <br />
        {{i.datetime}}
        <br />
        <img src="{{i.image.url}}"  width=400 height=400 />
        <br />
        <br />
        {{i.tweet}}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

View :

```
def myaccount(request):
    return render(request, 'tweets/myaccount.html', {'userstweet': Tweets.objects.all})
```

url :

```
path('myaccount', views.myaccount,name='account')
```

i expect the posts uploaded by the current logged in user will be shown on my account page but it gives nothing.

Comment: Can you share your ```models.py```?

Comment: class Tweets(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField('Date and Time')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    tweet = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Tweets'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't it better to just get the current user and query all Tweets by that user? What you can do is:

```
def myaccount(request):
    current_user = request.user
    # Where user is whatever foreign key you specified that relates to user.
    user_tweets = Tweets.objects.filter(user=current_user)

    return render(request, 'tweets/myaccount.html', {'userstweet': user_tweets})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by:

```py
def myaccount(request):
    return render(request, 'tweets/myaccount.html', {'userstweet': Tweets.objects.filter(user=request.user)})
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `request` in the django template.

eg.

```
{% if user == i.user %}
OR
{% if user.username == i.user.username  %}
```